# How can I generate an XML-schema from a class in a .NET Standard library?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd.exe, .net-standard-2.1

In the past I have been using xsd.exe to generate XML-schemas from classes in .NET framework libraries.

Now, I want to do the same for some classes in a .NET Standard 2.1 library, but I get an error.

Running

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\xsd.exe $(BinDir)$(TargetName).dll /type:$(ItemFileName)
```

from the Package Manager Console gives me:

> Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility [Microsoft (R)
> .NET Framework, Version 4.8.3928.0] Copyright (C) Microsoft
> Corporation. All rights reserved. Error: There was an error processing
> ''.
>
> - Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Maybe, this should have come as no surprise, but I cannot find documentation of a newer version of xsd.exe or of an alternative method for generating XML-schemas. There is no xsd.exe to be found in the .NET Core SDK's. And, in fact, the ticket [Port xsd.exe to .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1391), which is currently open, suggests that for .NET Core there is no support. The same could very well be true for .NET Standard.

*I would probably work if copied the classes to a .NET Framework project, but that just feels silly. Still, I may revert to that.*

Comment: Why don't you just use the .NET Standard library in the .NET Old project? That's what .NET Standard is for. To create libraries that can be shared among projects. It looks like the real problem is that the .NET Standard library is trying too big, and contains both DTOs that need to be shared among projects and other stuff that's only relevant to one of the projects

Comment: I suspect the real solution is to extract the DTOs into their own library and use that in all projects. In any case, `xsd.exe` is a legacy-legacy tool. It was replaced by `svcutil` when WCF came out in 2006, using better serializers and far better conformance to the (new then) schema and interoperability standards. In .NET Core the equivalent is the [dotnet-svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x) global tool

Comment: Why are you using `xsd` instead of `svcutil` anyway? `svcutil` is stricter than `xsd` so if you can't use `svcutil` to generate a schema, it means the class is problematic, not the tool, using constructs that can't be translated easily, like choice or anonymous types. `xsd` will cover such issues by using generic types like `XmlItem` which makes the resulting schema useless. In both tools you can control the schema using attributes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not sure I understand you correctly. An .NET Old project does not exists as such. Do you mean _solution_? I am not currently sharing this code between solutions. I do not think the actual code base is the issue, but the differences between the structure of a .NET framework and a .NET standard assembly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did not use `svcutil`, because I did not know of it's existence. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Net are you using.  I would make sure I was using Net 4.7.2 or newer and then Target your project for "Net Standard 2.1".  There were issues with older versions of Net when targeting other version of Net that were fixed.  So you get exception if you remove the option "/type:$(ItemFileName)".  I suspect the exception is occurring that the ItemFileName is not being found in the executable.

Comment: @jdweng I am using .NET Core 5.0 for the web application in the solution. I have now worked around the issue by creating a temporary solution and temporarily switched my assemblies to .NET Framework 4.7.2. This way I have obtained the schema. I plan to apply minor future changes in the classes to the schema manually.